# Blank createdon, createdby, modifiedon, modifiedby

Tags: dynamics-crm

[image]We inherited a client and something strange is going on with a few entities.

`Createdon`, `createdby`, `modifiedby`, and `modifiedon` do not get populated on create or update.

I am guessing something was done for import purposes, but need to revert back to original.

No plugins are altering the records.

Any ideas?

Turned off all plugins

Expected result: `Createdon`, `createdby`, `modifiedby`, and `modifiedon` to populate as normal

Actual result: `Createdon`, `createdby`, `modifiedby`, and `modifiedon` are blank.

Comment: Are you expecting the results in SQL Server or Dynamics?

Comment: Also what version of SQL?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Dynamics.

Comment: Need more info like you see any pattern on those entities or records (all or random?), any screenshot will be helpful. These are OOB fields and should populate by the platform without fail..

Comment: @ArunVinoth it happens to all records of this entity that are not imported, on create and update. Yes, I understand these are all OOB fields and should auto populate - what could possibly have been done to make them not populate? I will get you a screenshot.

Comment: While it is possible to modify those fields using a plugin or workflow, with all automation disabled they definitely should get populated. Did you check workflows too? One additional feature is that you can override the `CreatedOn` by pushing a value into `OverriddenCreatedOn`. This allows you to show the users a different created on value (e.g. from a legacy system), while the actual Dynamics create time will be in `RecordCreatedOn`. Is there anything in `OverriddenCreatedOn`? Are you certain you're looking at the OOB fields (vs. perhaps custom fields with the same display names)?

Comment: @Aron I will recheck - thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My analysis route will be like this:

1. Enable audit & see what's really going on for those records when created/updated (vs Imported records getting these values)
2. See any unsupported job or sql updates happening (if its on-premise)
3. Will create a MS support ticket for further assistance

I assume these are OOB fields and not custom fields hiding/showing based on some condition in footer. :)